# Orthogonal Matrices and Symplectic Matrices and Preservation of Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I would like to know the properties of orthogonal matrices and symplectic
    matrices in terms of the forms they preserve. Could someone please add and/or
    correct, maybe give some refs/examples?

AFAIK, given a quadratic form q
    on a vector space V over a field F, there is an associated orthogonal
    group O(2n) ,a subgroup of GL(n,F),  which 
    preserve q; if F is the reals O(2n) preserves q= inner-product and norm (since
    in R, the norm is induced by the inner-product).  Symplectic matrices only preserve symplectic forms, i.e., bilinear,antisymmetric,non-degenerate forms.

Are there relations between these groups; do they overlap, intersect, etc?

I am interested mostly in the case where the field is Z/2.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at artin's _geometric algebra_

Comment: Just a comment: given a nondegenerate quadratic form $q$, the group that preserves $q$ depends on the index of $q$. We obtain the orthogonal group when $q$ is positive definite, but when $q$ is not positive definite (but still nondegenerate) we can have other things. For example, when the index of $q$ is 1 (here the index of $q$ is the dimension of the "largest" subspace where $q$ is negative definite; I don't know if this definition is standard), we obtain the Lorentz group: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group .

Comment: as for the _geometric algebra_ here is a free copy http://www.archive.org/details/geometricalgebra033556mbp

Comment: Thanks a lot to both, very helpful; unfortunately I don't have the status necessary to give you points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over the reals the intersection of the orthogonal and symplectic groups in even dimension is isomorphic
to the unitary group in the half dimension.

$ U(n) = O(2n, \mathbf{R}) \cap Sp(2n, \mathbf{R})$

This is the [2 out of 3 property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group#2-out-of-3_property) expressing the compatibility the symplectic structure with the symmetric bilinear form of the orthogonal group.

The orthogonal group over $Z_2$ is a subgroup of the symplectic group because a symmetric bilinear form is also alternating (since $-1 = +1$).

The full symplectic group $Sp(2n, Z_2)$ can be realized from the action of the $2^n$ dimensional Clifford group on the bits of the binary
representation of the basis vectors (up to  a phase) as explained in [Daniel Gottesmann's](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/ams2009-talks/Gottesman-Paper.pdf)
 paper.

Comment: Thanks, David, that's what I was looking for.