# Symplectic and Euclidean structure invariance

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Consider a $2n$ real symplectic space - the usual $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Suppose that the same space could be endowed too with an Euclidean structure, by which the vectors of the symplectic basis are orthogonal.

In [*Symplectic Geometry* by A. T. Fomenko](https://books.google.it/books?id=SrXrqo5qaWQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=destroyed&f=false) it is said that

> Generally speaking, the connection between the Euclidean and the
>   symplectic structures is destroyed by any linear non-singular
>   transformation of $\mathbb R^{2n}$

I think that such "connection" is indeed preserved by transformations of the unitary group...am I wrong?

Comment: The short answer is "no, you are correct". The longer answer is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497092/over-the-reals-the-intersection-of-the-orthogonal-and-symplectic-groups-in-even